# How to view response from Spring 5 Reactive API in Postman?

Tags: spring, postman, spring-webflux

I have next endpoint in my application:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users")
public Mono<ServerResponse> users() {
    Flux<User> flux = Flux.just(new User("id"));
    return ServerResponse.ok()
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(flux, User.class)
            .onErrorResume(CustomException.class, e -> ServerResponse.notFound().build());
}
```

Currently I can see text `"data:"` as a body and `Content-Type →text/event-stream` in Postman. As I understand `Mono<ServerResponse>` always return data with `SSE(Server Sent Event)`.
Is it possible to somehow view response in Postman client?

Comment: Hi, are you sure you get a response using another consumer than postman ?

Comment: @Seb Actually I was just playing around with the code. Saw this example in documentation.

Comment: `Mono<ServerResponse>` does not always return data as SSE. It's either a WebFlux bug or something wrong in your setup. Can you try again with the latest milestone or open an issue on jira.spring.io with a sample project?

Comment: @BrianClozel I've created project using https://start.spring.io/. Selected latest `spring boot` and `reactive web`. Added rest controller with one endpoint that I've write above.

Comment: Such a project has no endpoint, so you're probably adding more to it. Please create a sample project and a JIRA issue.

Comment: @BrianClozel created https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15925

Comment: Thanks for creating this issue - I've just answered your question in both places. Sorry for not spotting that earlier in your original question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you're mixing the annotation model and the functional model in WebFlux. The `ServerResponse` class is part of the functional model.

Here's how to write an annotated endpoint in WebFlux:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity serverResponseMono() {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(Flux.just("test"));
    }
}
```

Here's the functional way now:

```
@Component
public class UserHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> findUser(ServerRequest request) {
        Flux<User> flux = Flux.just(new User("id"));
        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(flux, User.class)
                .onErrorResume(CustomException.class, e -> ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> users(UserHandler userHandler) {
        return route(GET("/test")
                  .and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), userHandler::findUser);
    }

}
```