# Difference between ResponseEntity<?> and ServerResponse

Tags: authentication, jwt

Can anyone please explain the difference between ServerResponse and ResponseEntity? I've seen both of them implemented differently in AuthenticationController class for authentication. Is one of these an alternative to the other?

Comment: Might be late but this answer will give you more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46050511